# NSDictionary and loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString * str = @"ABCDEFGHILMN";

NSDictionary *dictOdd = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"A",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"B",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"C",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"D",
                           ...............................
                          nil];

NSDictionary *dictEven = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"A",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"B",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"C",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], @"D",
                           ...............................
                          nil];

int sum  = 0;   
for (int i=1; i < [str length]; i++){
    if(i % 2){
        sum += [dictPair objectForKey:str[i]];
    }else{
        sum += [dictEven objectForKey:str[i]];
    }
}
```

I have created 2 dictionary for storage int numbers / letters, each letter have a int value.

I would make the sum of int numbers in relation to my str value, but i don't know how assign objectForKey:str[i]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `characterAtIndex:` which would leave you with

```
sum+=[[dictPair objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",[str characterAtIndex:i]]] intValue];
```

Comment: That should technically be `%C`, I think, since `characterAtIndex:` returns a unichar.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this, according to [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Remember that NSNumber and int are different and you should convert before adding them.

```
NSString *str = ...

NSDictionary *dictOdd = ...
NSDictionary *dictOdd = ...

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [str length];  i++) {

   if(i % 2 == 0)
        sum += [[dictPair objectForKey:[str characterAtIndex:i]] intValue];
   else
        sum += [[dictEven objectForKey:[str characterAtIndex:i]] intValue];
}
```